# Negate findall in Python re module

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I would like to strip every instance of a solution environment in a `.tex` file (i.e., text between `\begin{solution}` and `\end{solution}`) and save the output to a new file.

The code snippet below grabs the solution environment: How can I negate that to strip it instead?

Applying a "negation" caret `^` as in `re.findall(r'^\\begin{solution}(.*?)\\end{solution}', data, re.S)` works [here](https://regex101.com/r/JGTzst/2), but did not work for me within a Python session (it returned an empty list `[]`). I did try to wrap with parentheses.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
data = open(file).read()
re.findall(r'\\begin{solution}(.*?)\\end{solution}', data, re.S)
```

Eventually I'll strip the two empty lines that are created by the substitution and save the cleaned text to a new file (without overwriting).

**Input:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\title{Strip the solutions environment}
% solution environment
\newenvironment{solution}
  {\noindent\textbf{Solution:\newline}}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Objectives}
None whatsoever:
\begin{itemize}
\item True
\item False
\end{itemize}

\begin{solution}
The correct answer is True. 
% adding a comment here
\begin{comment}
make this a bit of a challenge with a nested environment:

~   tilde
`   backtick
{   open brace
}   close brace
[   open bracket
]   close bracket
!   exclamation mark
%   percent
^   carat
*   asterisk
–   hyphen
=   equals
+   plus
_   underscore
|   pipe
\   backslash
/   forward slash
@   at
:   colon
;   semicolon
<   less than
>   greater than
?   question mark
.   period
,   comma
#   pound
&   ampersand
$   dollar
(   open parenthesis
)   close parenthesis
\end{comment}
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

**Expected output:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\title{Strip the solutions environment}
% solution environment
\newenvironment{solution}
  {\noindent\textbf{Solution:\newline}}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Objectives}
None whatsoever:
\begin{itemize}
\item True
\item False
\end{itemize}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: `^` is a negation only inside a character class. I believe what you want is using `re.sub` to replace the matches with the empty string. Also, be aware that using `(.*?)` with `re.S` may be slow since it might trigger catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: Use `re.sub` with the same regex

Comment: You probably just want `re.sub(r'^\\begin{solution}.*?\\end{solution}', '', data, flags=re.S | re.M)`. The regex101 has both `m` and `s` flags, you only used `re.S`.

Comment: I'm very new to regex. If you believe this is a duplicate, please point me in the right direction and I'll close this question. thanks @ctwheels for showing me how to escape `\\` and pointing me to regex101.com.

Comment: Further to @Bakuriu's point, a carat, `^`, denotes the start of the string, unless `re.MULTILINE` (or `re.M`) is specified, in which case `^` denotes the start of a line. If `^` is the first character in a character class, the character class matches any single character other than the one(s) following `^`. `[^ab^]`, for example, matches any character other than `'a'`, `'b'` or `'^'`.

Comment: `data = re.sub(r'(?m)^\\begin({solution})(?:.*\n)+\\end\1', '', data)` would be more efficient.

Comment: PatrickT, although @Wiktor always gives excellent answers, I suggest that when posting any question to SO you wait awhile (a few hours, say) before selecting one. There are a few reasons for that. Firstly, and probably most important, is that some readers may choose not to provide a potentially excellent answer if an  answer has already been selected. Secondly, answers are sometimes incorrect and readers may be less likely to spot the flaw if the answer has been selected. There is no rush to select an answer, just don't forget to do so (provided at least one answer has been helpful to you).

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland I'll just wait. The two blank lines are not deleted. It isn't a big deal of course.

Comment: The net count is the single number that you see before clicking.

Comment: I'd never noticed the breakdown of upvotes/downvotes before, thanks @Barmar

Comment: @PatrickT: `r'\n\\begin({solution})(?:.*\n)+\\end\1\n'` would be suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this regex to remove a block from start marker to end marker including line breaks before and after the block:

```bash
\n\\begin({solution})(?:.*\n)+?\\end\1\n
```

And replace this with empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JGTzst/3)

**Code:**

```bash
import re
data = re.sub(r'\n\\begin({solution})(?:.*\n)+?\\end\1\n', '', data)
```

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `\n`: Match a line break
- `\\begin`: Match text `\begin`
- `({solution})`: Match `{solution}` and grab it in capture group #1
- `(?:.*\n)+?`: Match any test followed by a line break. Repeat this group 1+ times and make this a lazy match
- `\\end`: Match text `\end`
- `\1`: Match same text as in capture group #1
- `\n`: Match a line break

Comment: Just what the doctor ordered, thank you so much anubhava! Out of curiosity would this work for a starred environment? as in `\n\\begin({solution*})(?:.*\n)+?\\end\1\n`

Comment: An `*` after `n` will only let `n` match 0 and more times so you can match `solutio` or `solution` or `solutionn` or `solutionnnnnn` etc. If you want to match anything after `solution` inside `{` and `}` then use `{solution[^}]*}`

Comment: Thanks again @anubhava! your explanations are the gem!

Comment: I just realize this will stop after the first match. Can you point me to the correct approach for multiple occurrences in the same file? For short replacements, I would read the file line by line, but here I need to read multiple lines, so how would I go about that? Thanks!

Comment: It matches multiple times. Even in the linked demo https://regex101.com/r/JGTzst/3 you can see that there are 2 matches.

Comment: Oh, yes! Thank you so much! Apparently I was using the version you had given in an early comment below my question, before properly answering. I had not noticed an important difference: the extra question mark, which now I understand serves to indicate matching multiple occurences! I was using this `re.sub(r'(?m)^\\begin({solution})(?:.*\n)+\\end\1', '', data)`. You know, I'm starting to like this regex magic!

Comment: A `+?` makes it a non-greedy or lazy match instead of `.+` which is a greedy match that matches longest possible match.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent teaching anubhava! :-)